# Time reversal of Bloch Hamiltonian (at TRIM points)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry

I know that time-reversal symmetry requires the Bloch Hamiltonian $H(\textbf{k})$ to transform as:
$$
\Theta H(\textbf{k}) \Theta^{-1}=H(-\textbf{k})
$$
where $\Theta$ is the time-reversal operator.

Now, let me consider the Bloch Hamiltonian at some time-reversal invariant momenta (TRIM) $\Gamma_i$ (i.e. $-\Gamma_i=\Gamma_i + \textbf{G}$ for some reciprocal lattice vector $\textbf{G}$). Then, as I have seen in many places (including [this paper by Fu & Kane](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0611341), just below Eq.(2.2)), people would claim that
$$
\Theta H(\Gamma_i) \Theta^{-1}=H(-\Gamma_i)=H(\Gamma_i)
$$
and then the Kramers theorem can be applied to argue that the band is degenerate at TRIM points.

What confuses me here is that I don't know why $H(-\Gamma_i)=H(\Gamma_i)$. I am tempted to think that $H(\textbf{k}+\textbf{G})=H(\textbf{k})$, which would then imply $H(-\Gamma_i)=H(\Gamma_i+\textbf{G})=H(\Gamma_i)$, but I cannot prove this statement either.

People may say that $\textbf{k}$ and $\textbf{k+G}$ are the same point in the 1st BZ, so it is "obvious" that $H(\textbf{k}+\textbf{G})=H(\textbf{k})$. But I am skeptical. Well, I can show that $E(\textbf{k}+\textbf{G})=E(\textbf{k})$ for the folded band dispersion, but the band dispersion and the Bloch Hamiltonian are really two things.

Ultimately, if $H(\textbf{k})=H(\textbf{k}+\textbf{G})$, I want to see this from the basic definition of the Bloch Hamiltonian: $H(\textbf{k})=e^{-i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}H e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}$. When I naively put $\textbf{k}+\textbf{G}$ into the definition, I don't see an immediate way to equate $H(\textbf{k})=H(\textbf{k}+\textbf{G})$.

It seems to be a trivial question but somehow I am stuck in it. Any comments on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Bloch Hamiltonians are always  periodic and its "period" is the first BZ, if the hopping integrals are translational invariant.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to treat $k$ as a good quantum number, which is not the case for system with lattice (discrete translational symmetry). $k$ out of BZ makes no sense but artificially defined as something the same as their conterpart $k+G$ in BZ.

Consider free particle
$$
H=\sum_{k\in R^3} c_k^\dagger \frac{k^2}{2m} c_k
$$
You can see this as a system with only discrete translational symmetry
$$
H=\sum_{k\in BZ} (\sum_{i\in Z^3}c_{k+G_i}^\dagger \frac{(k+G_i)^2}{2m} c_{k+G_i})
$$
and define for $k \in BZ$
$$
H_k=\sum_{i\in Z^3}c_{k+G_i}^\dagger \frac{(k+G_i)^2}{2m} c_{k+G_i}
$$
define for $k \notin BZ$
$$
H_k=H_{k+G_i}
$$
So, you fold the bands in BZ and it seems natural that $H_k$ is periodic with k.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am actually aware of the fact that $k$ is the crystal momentum, and we fold the energy dispersion so that $k$ lives in the first BZ (as you can see in the description). If $H(k)=H(k+G)$, I want to start the proof from the basic definition of the Bloch Hamiltonian: $H(k)=e^{-ikr}He^{ikr}$. You deliberately decomposed the free-particle Hamiltonian into a sum of Hamiltonians that are periodic in the k-space, but I don't see the immediate link between this periodic Hamiltonian and $H(k)=e^{-ikr}He^{ikr}$, even after the second-quantization of H(k).

Comment: I tend to think $H(k)\neq H(k+G)$ in the strict sense, i.e. if directly following the definition of the Bloch Hamiltonian. When people write down $H(k) = H(k+G)$, maybe they mean it "loosely": the band dispersion is folded, and that's it. I have now realised that we don't need $H(k) = H(k+G)$ (strict sense) to apply Kramer's theorem at TRIM points: $\Theta |u_\Gamma\rangle$ and $|u_\Gamma\rangle$ are  two eigenstates of "different" Hamiltonians (one at $\Gamma$, one at $-\Gamma$) but they do appear at the same point in the folded band structure, so there is indeed degeneracy. How do you think?

Comment: I have to say they are equal in a very strict sense and you don't need to avoid it. I think a proof is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should see the problem in a different angle instead of following the paper's logical flow. Here, one only considers the first Brillouin zone and has that $\Theta_kH(k)\Theta^{-1}_k=H(-k)$ for all $k$. TRIM are points that satisfy $[H(k),\Theta_k]=0$, which yields $-\Gamma_i=\Gamma_i$. However, since the Brillouin zone is defined in a torus, the author generalizes the result that $-\Gamma_i=\Gamma_i+\mathbf{G}$.
Not only TRIM, one can also find inversion invariant momenta in the same manner.